# Disable css styling in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm trying to fit a DataTables table inside a Bootstrap panel.

I have tried setting the option `dom` as:

```
dom: '<"panel panel-default"<"panel-heading"lf>t<"panel-footer"ip>>',
```

The elements are placed correctly where they should, but DataTables applies alot of styling to the elements, so the layout is quite ugly.

Can I disable the css styling? For instance, DataTables aligns the filtering and pagination at right, which seems to be done with `position: absolute` or something. I would rather use Bootstrap's `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6">....` or just `<div class="pull-right">...</div>`.

## Edit

Thank you for your answers

I have tried disabling styling with

```
.dataTables_length {
}

.dataTables_length label {
  float: none !important;
}

.dataTables_filter {
}

.dataTables_filter label {
  float: none !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.dataTables_info {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}

.dataTables_paginate {
  float: none !important;
}

.dataTables_paginate ul.pagination {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

and made the columns with

```
dom: '<"panel panel-default"<"panel-heading"<"row"<"col-md-6"l><"col-md-6 text-right"f>>>t<"panel-footer"<"row"<"col-md-6"i><"col-md-6 text-right"p>>>>',
```

It almost works but I guess I should rather add `col-md-6` as class to the existing div elements instead of adding more div elements in the dom option.

Is this really the correct way to do it?

Comment: Datatables has support for Bootstrap (http://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html). Are you including the necessary datatables->boostrap scripts/styles ?

Comment: I am using DataTables through https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular which uses the bootstrap styles

Comment: But the styling of the bootstrap panel does work as inteded.. It's just some extra styling done by DataTables which messes the table up

Comment: Gotcha. Datatables does have the ability to customize their theme, but it is fairly limited (colors, borders, etc.). You may need to override the incorrect behavior by creating a custom stylesheet that fixes whatever is wrong. Unfortunately, that is limited to CSS styling, not full-blown HTML template modifications.

Comment: See my updated answer. I really not like the `dom` option, it is too complicated and you will run into a struggle when you at some other point need to change your layout. Keep it simple.

Comment: Solution with `dom` is a correct one, that's the right way to do it, see http://jsfiddle.net/a62hqqf9/.

Comment: @Gyrocode, you should produce that into an answer, but I stick to my experience and feeling. If you change the layout, and rely on dom, then you have to struggle with both layout and dom. I prefer just to struggle with layout - after all, dataTables is a subset of the rendered webpage and should by that also be a subset of the overall layout.

Answer (score 0):

It simply goes on CSS classes - `.dataTables_<context>`, here is some CSS to play around with :

```css
.dataTables_length {
    background-color: red;
}
.dataTables_filter {
    background-color: blue;
}
.dataTables_info {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.dataTables_paginate {
    background-color: green;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/g860g5bm/**

If you want to alter the classes for those elements, then you have `id`'s on the scheme `<id>_<context>` :

```css
#example_length {
    background-color: red;
}
#example_filter {
    background-color: blue;
}
#example_info {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#example_paginate {
    background-color: green;
}
```

completely alter the class for the lengthmenu :

```js
$('#example_length').removeClass().addClass('col-md-6');
```

---

If you want something like `<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6">` for example for the lenghtmenu - then use jQuerys [**`wrap`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) :

```
$('#example_length')
   .wrap($('<div>', { 'class' : 'row' }))
   .wrap($('<div>', { 'class' : 'col-md-6' }))
```

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Bootstrap requires certain structure in [`dom`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option, see [Styling](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom#Styling) for more information.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": '<"panel panel-default"<"panel-heading"<"row"<"col-md-6"l><"col-md-6 text-right"f>>>t<"panel-footer"<"row"<"col-md-6"i><"col-md-6 text-right"p>>>>'
});
```

> The styling libraries that DataTables supports will override the default value of the `dom` parameter and replace it with a value that is suitable for their layout system. For example the Bootstrap integration makes use of Bootstrap's grid layout.
>
> ```js
> "dom":
>    "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
>    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
>    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>"
> ```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a62hqqf9/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: In your example, there is a small spacing between the panel-heading and the table because the table has the class `dataTable`.